# change bootstrap dropdown caret

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I`m working on bootstrap 3
I have little drodown

```
<div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle selectcity"
                                            data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="selectedcity">City</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Tbilisi</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Moscow</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

on the caret is default dropdown triangle
and I need to change with this

```
.selectcity .caret {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.selectcity .caret:before {
    content: "";
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 5px solid #36b0d9;
    border-left: 5px solid #36b0d9;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
.selectcity .caret:after {
    content: "";
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #36b0d9;
    border-right: 5px solid #36b0d9;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
.selectcity .caret:hover:before,
.selectcity .caret:hover:after {
    border-color: #1e5c75;
}
```

but I do not know caret default width and height
+ I can not remove the default triangle
please help me.

how can I do this?

Comment: Why not replace `<span class="caret"></span>` with something else, like a Bootstrap glyphicon?

Comment: becouse I need something like this http://s018.radikal.ru/i528/1503/40/06d9218f072b.png

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please can you explain it whether you want to apply button css to the drop down or want to change button css

Comment: I need to change dropdown icon
becouse bootstrap dropdown has caret
I need to change it design

I understand that caret default height and width is zero and on borders has #000 color.

so I add on the caret border-top:0 solid transparent;
with this css rule default caret triangle is disabled or hiden. as you want.

now I want to add my own triangle on the button but I can not understand how many I need height and width
please check this fiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/giasoft/kz71p9ub/

this is what I have in this time

and on the image wich is added in the last post is what I need to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you already did was great, here is what you were asking for :

```
.selectcity .caret {
    border-top:2px solid #36b0d9;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid #36b0d9;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all 0.6s;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:4px;
}
.selectcity .caret:before {
    content:"";
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    border-top:2px solid #36b0d9;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid #36b0d9;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.selectcity:hover .caret, .selectcity:hover .caret:before {
    border-color:#1e5c75;
}
```

> [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhrs6sLt/)

---

`.selectcity .caret {...}` Render a square (8px*8px) with only border top and left. In order to get an arrow, this square is rotated (45deg), this way the corder is on top. This is your first arrow.

`.selectcity .caret:before {...}` do the job for the second arrow, but instead of a rotation of 45deg, this is 180deg to get the corner to the bottom.